# strncmp in python

Tags: python

I am parsing through a file with a list of paths. I am trying to see if one path is under a specific directory or not. So I have two strings: `S1 = '/tmp/'` and `S2 = '/tmp/file.txt'`

If I want to check if `S2` contains `S1` plus some extra bytes, in C, I would do a `strncmp` of `S1` and `S2` upto `strlen(S1)` bytes. Is there a way to do that in Python? I am new to Python and do not know all the modules available to me yet. I could implement this trivially by just iterating over the characters in the strings and comparing, but want to find out if there is anything that gives me these kind of helper functions by default

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes.  You can do:  `if a in b:`  That will check if `a` is a substring anywhere in `b`.

e.g.

```
if 'foo' in 'foobar':
    print True

if 'foo' in 'barfoo':
    print True
```

From your post, it appears you want to only look at the start of the strings.  In that case, you can use the `.startswith` method:

```
if 'foobar'.startswith('foo'):
    print "it does!"
```

Similarly, you can do the same thing with `endswith`:

```
if 'foobar'.endswith('bar'):
    print "Yes sir :)"
```

finally, maybe the most literal translation of `strncmp` would be to use slicing and `==`:

```
if a[:n] == b[:n]:
    print 'strncmp success!'
```

Python also has many facilities for dealing with path names in the [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) module.  It's worth investigating what is in there.  There are some pretty neat functions.

Comment: Yours is probably more pythonic, but I think slicing should also be considered. +1

Comment: Wow. This is exactly the kind of thing I was hoping python has. I was told python is awesome and so far has not been disappointed.

Comment: @R11 -- python has a few qwirks that trip almost everyone up in the beginning, but once you've figured those out, it's really a joy to work with.  Good luck!

Comment: In contrast to `strcmp()` then all those examples are useless.

Answer (score 5):

You're probably looking for `os.path.commonprefix`.

for example: `os.path.commonprefix(['/tmp/','/tmp/file.txt'])` will return `'/tmp/`

so you should check for `len(os.path.commonprefix([s1,s2])) > 0`

Check out docs here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

Comment: This is an interesting take on the problem.  +1 for thinking outside the box.

Comment: Nice! I really like this one too. Does it also handle OS specific notations like windows paths starting with "C:\\tmp\" instead of the "/tmp/"? I did not have this in mid at all when I posted. I was just hoping to find some string maniulation tricks. But awesome!

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure how it works with windows and I have no windows box to check myself, but I would guess that no. It does seem like a more accurate way to check if a path is a subpath. I just noticed that you were doing path manipulation which C might not have a specialized module, for but python has `os.path`. A lot of programmers come to python from other backgrounds and reinvent those functions (in non portable ways usually) so I felt like it was a good idea to showcase the standard library. Remember, python comes with batteries included :D

Comment: @rgrinberg - That is exactly what I wanted to avoid with python. I don't want to spend writing helper functions, rather want to spend time on the actual problem logic. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can test that by

```
S2[:len(S1)] == S1
```

or even simpler:

```
S2.startswith(S1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `find` method of a string

```
>>> s1 = "/tmp"
>>> s2 = "/tmp/file.txt"
>>> s2.find(s1)
0
```